# can EventBus be used on only one activity?

Tags: android, event-bus

I am trying to get some values from an API endpoint, and onclick of a  button I want it to show the values on some editTexts but in the same activity.i.e the button and the editTEXTS are on the same screen. How do i do that?

Comment: I think there is an issue with clarity here. Do you have any fragments? If everything is in one activity then you can directly reference the various EditTexts and Buttons. EventBus is for going between different Activities and Fragments (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score -1):

So why you want to use EventBus mainly if all your resources are in the same activity? you can update them easily without using EventBus that's why i'm asking.